# Загрузить данные из Excel нестандартной структуры

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, excel, обработка-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Нужно загрузить данные из екселя используя pandas.read_excel. Сам ексель файл представляет собой следующую структуру:
Первые несколько строчек ненужная информация , потом названия столбцов в строке, потом опять ненужная , ниже в столбце индексы, а напротив в строках данные. (Схематическое изображение на рисунке: trash - ненужные данные которые нужно пропустить)
У меня получилось написать функцию, которая может читать ексель такого типа, но препод сказал, что файл нужно именно парсить и можно использовать магические команды, а я использую константы (например в skiprows). Я прочитала всю документацию по функции pandas.read_excel , но не нашла ничего про эти команды. Что можно сделать, чтобы читать используя магические команды и парсить? (даже если не пандас библиотека). Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: В Pandas API более 1000 магических и не очень методов и для того, чтобы посоветовать наиболее подходящие именно для этой задачи методы, нужно видеть пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат...

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, дополнила вопрос ожидаемым результатом и то как я делаю это сейчас. А нужно с помощью магических команд. Посмотрите ,  пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм действий:

1. создаём функцию `is_trash(cell_vall)`, которая определяет является ли значение ячейки "мусором" и возвращает True для таких значений.
2. парсим Excel файл, используя `pd.read_excel()`.
3. заменяем значения тех ячеек, для которых функция `is_trash(cell_vall)` вернет `True` на `NaN`.
4. используем магическую функцию [DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) для удаления ячеек с мусором.

---

Если в будущем вы захотите получить ответ с проверенным примером кода (реализации), то воспользуйтесь следующим алгоритмом:

1. Ознакомьтесь с тем [как задать хороший вопрос на SO](http://%5B%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81?%5D(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) и  [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. Откройте новый SO вопрос согласно рекомендациям описанным по ссылкам выше.
3. Приведите в теле вопроса [**воспроизводимый** пример входных данных (**в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл**) и **то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/).

Comment: А в теле функции is_trash() какого вида проверку нужно сделать? И какие туда аргументы подавать? полный перебор делать? логика процесса понятна, но вот насчет этой функции что то вопросы как ее реализовать

Comment: @МарияПитонистка, предвидя этот вопрос, я написал вторую часть ответа ;) Для того чтобы реализовать `is_trash()` нужно понимать какие у вас данные и что именно вы считаете мусором.

Comment: для примера используем ексель, который у меня в шапке вопроса . Мне вот только не ясно как сам цикл будет выглядеть, какими средствами перебор осуществляться?

Comment: @МарияПитонистка, я не смогу вам помочь без __воспроизводимого__ примера данных и результата. Выложите небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных (Excel) на какой-нибудь файлообменник и результат, который вы хотите получить.